# Iterate through IEnumerable string array

Tags: c#, linq

I'm reading a multiple line text file which has comma delimited values like this:

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
 IEnumerable<string[]> resultArray1 = lines.Select(x => x.Split(','));
```

In debug mode when I look at the results they look like this:

```
[0] drill down to see [0] "3.22"
                      [1] "4.00
```

With the following loop, I can print out the values, but I'm not sure how to do it without specifying the [0] and [1] and I'm not sure how to know which line I'm on of the file. I have this so far:

```
  foreach (string line in lines)
  {
      foreach (string[] item in resultArray1)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(item[0]);
          Console.WriteLine(item[1]);
      }
  }
```

Could you show me what am I missing?

Comment: What do you want to do with the line itself? It would help if you could give us more detail about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you looking to print out all the contents of each item of resultArray1? Or only specific ones?

Comment: Don't trust the results of Linq queries in the debugger.  Linq just adds enumarators around a concrete list so you cannot tell what the actual results are.  Hydrate to a list or array first.

Comment: I guess you can't ask questions here without getting down votes. Awesome.

Comment: Don't take in personally - read the comments to see how to make your question more clear and maybe you'll get upvotes.  Hopefully a good answer to your question is more important to you than upvotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For printing out the separate elements in `string[]`, I would use a `for` loop:

```
  foreach (string[] item in resultArray1)
  {
      for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
          Console.WriteLine(item[i]);
  }
```

As for keeping track of what line of the file you are on, have a separate variable keep track of that or change your `foreach` to a `for`. Below is the variable implementation:

```
int line = 0;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    //Code here

    line++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If each line contains only two values, you can do bellow.

```
public class Data
{
    public string Property1 { set; get; }
    public string Property2 { set; get; }
}

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        IEnumerable<Data> resultArray1 = lines.Select(x =>
        {
            var line = x.Split(',');
            return new Data
            {
                Property1 = line[0],
                Property2 = line[1],
            };
        });

        //And loop through the enumeration.
        foreach (var line in resultArray1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line.Property1);
            Console.WriteLine(line.Property2);
        }
```

Comment: This looks helpful too. Thanks

Comment: when you have a list or passing some data as parameters, It is always a good practice to use objects instead of simple data types such strings or bools..etc.